# Why does proving $\lim_{h\to 0} (X(t + h) - X(t)) = 0$ prove continuity?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Why does proving $\lim_{h\to 0} (X(t + h) - X(t)) = 0$ prove continuity?

I don't think it matters, but more specifically, $X(t)$ is a Brownian motion.

I thought that a function $f$ is continuous at the point $x_0$ provided that the image sequence converges to the image point when the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x_0$.

So wouldn't this only prove continuity at $0$? Or, how does it work?

Comment: maybe it's not time to be doing Brownian motion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought that a function $f$ is continuous at the point $x_0$ provided that the image sequence converges to the image point when the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x_0$.

The function is $X$, the sequence is $\{t_h:t_h=(t+h)\}$, the image point is $t_0=t$.

To say that the image sequence converges to the image point is to say $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}X(t_h)=X(t_0)$ or...$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\big(X(t+h)-X(t)\big) = 0$$

Thus this is true for all $t$ in the domain, exactly when the function $X$ is continuous everywhere over that domain.

Comment: So for each index $h$, we're defining $t_{h} = t + h$? But as $h \to \infty,$ wouldn't $t_{h}$ converge to $\infty$?

Comment: We're approaching $h\to 0$ not infinity.

Comment: How come we can choose $h \to 0$? For convergence of $\{x_{n}\}$, for example, shouldn't we consider $n \to \infty$?

Comment: You want to know what happens as you converge *towards* the limit point.

Comment: $\tfrac 1 h\to\infty$ if you prefer.

Comment: Okay, I understand from $\frac{1}{h} \to \infty$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $t_n \to t$ then $X(t_n)-X(t)=X((t_n-t)+t)-X(t)$ so just note that $h_n=t_n-t \to 0$.